# How can I activate extra-verbose mode (debugging mode) during Debian boot?

Tags: debian, kernel, boot, debugging, dmesg

How do I activate extra verbosity during boot, on Debian? I removed the `quiet` parameter and tried to add `debug` but it didn't help.

My problem is that my keyboard takes 2-3 min to activate so it slows my startup tremendously since I need to unlock a partition. I would like to get the message that pops out the moment my keyboard gets activated, but removing `quiet` doesn't print it.

Comment: What is going on that it takes 2-3 minutes to activate your keyboard?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 that's what i'm trying to find out. I asked a question here on what might cause it but nobody was able to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [list of all possible boot parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html).  I've never used it, but try adding `ignore_loglevel`:

> Ignore loglevel setting - this will print /all/ kernel messages to the console.  Useful for debugging.  We also add it as printk module parameter, so users could change it dynamically, usually by /sys/module/printk/parameters/ignore_loglevel.

I previously mentioned `verbose`, but actually that only applies to other specific kernel options like acpi, as you can read, above.

With an understanding of your exact hardware, like it seems you have, you can go even deeper with [`arch/arm/Kconfig.debug`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/Kconfig.debug)

Comment: If you want more help, please also add more details, because it sounds like a very interesting setup.

Comment: I added verbose parameter but it didn't help. I remember that one time I added the `debug` parameter to a fedora derived kernel and I had a very high number of messages during the boot, even while it was waiting for my input to unlock a partition. Here even after adding `verbose` it remains silent after it asks me for the key.

Comment: I added some sources and suggestion to try options specific to your keyboard or also `ignore_loglevel`.  I hope that as you dig deeper into this stuff, you'll find answers to several of your recent questions.

Comment: well `ignore_loglevel` nailed it thanks, looks like the system is cycling through all the usb ports and the keyboard gets activated only when it reach the good one. The cycling takes a long time it says `usb 1-3: new high speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd; devce descriptor read/8, error -110` for each empty port and get stuck 10seconds on each one before it reaches the keyboard.

Comment: @ChiseledAbs that is really interesting, thanks for the follow-up and marking the answer.  Glad you're making progress.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the verbose (debugging) mode of the bootloader (is it grub?) will give you some hints.

To activate this press "c" during the bootloader menu (>Kernel Parameter) and then execute "set debug=all".

But since the bootloader is taking a long time before the keyboard becomes available to the system, the fault is somewhere else. To get more details during boot it is possible to use kernel-parameters for a higher verbosity level.

What about the connection Keyboard to the machine (Is it wired ? / USB ? / etc.)?